# Should I stripe Cassandra commit log?

Tags: cassandra

Is there any benefit in striping the Cassandra commit log? For example, create a RAID1 of multiple disks. If each commit log flush is large enough (larger than stripe size) will it take advantage of the multiple spindles?

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen any Cassandra deployments limited by I/O writing the commit log.  Much more I/O will be generated by flushing memtables, compaction and reads.

RAID1 is mirroring so would only increase reliability.  This is unlikely to be worth it since the commitlog is replicated through normal Cassandra replication.

Striping with RAID0 might help write throughput for the commitlog but I doubt you'd notice any  overall performance improvement.

Comment: We use commitlog_sync: batch because we cannot afford any data loss. In our case the commit log is the bottleneck.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the commit log volume is indeed a bottleneck or is this just an assertion?  C* tends to be CPU bound on writes until flushing and compaction occurs and that I/O is on the data volume(s) which are typically separate media from the commit log.

Comment: Is it a bottleneck or just slowest part? Batch relies on commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms so writes will usually take commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms + your disk write latency.